# compare two property files and replace values

Tags: shell, unix

I have two  files File_A and File_B containing key/value pairs

File_A

```
ANT_HOME=/opt/apps/apache-ant
HIBERNATE=/opt/apps/some/path/to/hibernate
BATCHDAEMON=false
BATCHEDIT_ENABLED=false
BATCHENABLED=false
----
----
<120 lines)
```

File_B

```
ANT_HOME=$ANT_DIR
HIBERNATE=$HIBERNATE_LOCATION
----
DBCONNECTION=
DBNAME=
DBUSER=
DBPASS=
DBPORT=
DBSERVER=

<70 lines>
```

I want to compare keys in File_A to Keys in File_B and if there is a match substitute values from File_B into file_A

End Result

File_A
    ANT_HOME=$ANT_DIR
    HIBERNATE=$HIBERNATE_LOCATION
    DBCONNECTION=
    DBNAME=
    DBUSER=
    DBPASS=
    DBPORT=
    DBSERVER=
    ....
    <120 Lines>

Also some of the  values have "=" in them
for example

```
SOME_PASSWD=Qwcnyt2-49zstyq4=
```

so I have been using regexp to get first occurrence of values before "="

I am using awk to see if I am getting desired result but, I am not able to get substitution right.

```
 awk 'BEGIN {FS = "/[^=]*/"} FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } $1 in array { sub ($1, array[$2])} 1' File_B, File_A >> some_tempfile.ini
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea to parse File_B first is good.

If the field separator (FS) is set to **=**, then **$1** directly gives the key for the current line. This leads to use an associative array.

Give this tested version a try:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="="; } { if (NR==FNR) { pkeynline[$1]=$0; } else if (pkeynline[$1]) { print pkeynline[$1]; } else { print; } }'
```

The test:

```
$ cat File_A
ANT_HOME=/opt/apps/apache-ant
HIBERNATE=/opt/apps/some/path/to/hibernate
BATCHDAEMON=false
BATCHEDIT_ENABLED=false
BATCHENABLED=false
SOME_PASSWD=

$ cat File_B
ANT_HOME=$ANT_DIR
HIBERNATE=$HIBERNATE_LOCATION
SOME_PASSWD=Qwcnyt2-49zstyq4=
UNIQ_KEY_FILEB=/home/life/is/great

$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="="; } { if (NR==FNR) { pkeynline[$1]=$0; } else if (pkeynline[$1]) { print pkeynline[$1]; } else { print; } }' File_B File_A > some_tempfile.ini

$ cat some_tempfile.ini
ANT_HOME=$ANT_DIR
HIBERNATE=$HIBERNATE_LOCATION
BATCHDAEMON=false
BATCHEDIT_ENABLED=false
BATCHENABLED=false
SOME_PASSWD=Qwcnyt2-49zstyq4=
```